# Error in Test class for uploading a CSV through Visualforce

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

```
public class importDataFromCSVController {
public static blob csvFile{get;set;}
    public static String csvAsString{get;set;}
    public static string[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
   
    public static list<Raw_Data__c> datalist = new list<raw_data__c>();
   
    public static list<Raw_data__c> getdatalist(){
        return datalist;
    }
   
   
    public static void import_Raw_Data()
    { datalist.clear();
        csvAsString = csvFile.toString();
        csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');
       
        for(integer i=0;i<csvFileLines.size();i++)
        {
            raw_data__c obj = new raw_data__C();
             string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
            obj.name = csvRecordData[0];
           
            obj.Salary__c = Double.valueOf(string.valueOf(csvRecordData[1]));
            if(obj !=null)
            {
            datalist.add(obj);
            }
          }
}
}
```

---

```
@isTest
public class TestClass_Task_8 {

    static String str = 'Name,Salary__c';
   
   public static String[] csvFileLines;
    public static Blob csvFileBody;

    static testmethod void testfileupload(){
        Test.startTest();      
        csvFileBody = Blob.valueOf(str);
        String csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
        csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');

        TestClass_Task_8 importData = new TestClass_Task_8();
        importData.csvFileBody = csvFileBody;
        importData.import_Raw_Data();
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    static testmethod void testfileuploadNegative(){
        Test.startTest();      
        csvFileBody = Blob.valueOf(str);
        String csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
        csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');

        TestClass_Task_8 importData = new TestClass_Task_8();
        importData.import_Raw_Data();
        Test.stopTest();
    }

   
}
```

[image]

Comment: Kinda hard to help if you don't tell us what the error is. [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: Yes I uploaded a image of error that I'm faced in test class

Comment: Why are any of these items marked `static`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are compilation errors.  The system is telling you that it doesn't understand your code.  The line numbers tell you were the problematic code is, although sometimes the actual error occurs in another spot.  For example, the "Method does not exist..." errors occur on the two lines that contain `importData.import_Raw_Data();`, but the actual problem is that your `importData` object in that line is the wrong type of object.  In both test methods, you have this line:

```
TestClass_Task_8 importData = new TestClass_Task_8();
```

You are creating a new instance of your test class, NOT the class you need to test (`importDataFromCSVController`).  Change those lines to:

```
TestClass_Task_8 importData = new importDataFromCSVController();
```

Your first test method also contains the line:

```
importData.csvFileBody = csvFileBody;
```

However, `importDataFromCSVController` doesn't have a public `csvFileBody` property/variable.  I suspect that line should be:

```
importData.csvFileLines = csvFileLines;
```